# Strange answer using PCRE Regex

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I'm using the PCRE regex lib in C (http://www.pcre.org/) to parse and match my HTML string. To simplify my question, suppose I got the source string: ***"aaa:  bbbb:"***, and my pattern: **a(.*?):|b(.*?):**, the symbol **?** indicate that it's a non-greedy match, so the answer should be two matchups: one is **"aaa:"** and the other **"bbbb:"**,

then I programmed:

```
char *src = "aaa:  bbbb:";
char *pattern = "a(.*?):|b(.*?):";
pcre *re = NULL;

//---missing out---

re = pcre_compile(pattern,  // pattern,  
                  0,            // options,   
                  &error,       // errptr,   
                  &erroffset,   // erroffset,  
                  NULL);        // tableptr, 
while (
      (rc = pcre_exec(re,     // regex ptr,   
               NULL,          // extra arg,   
               src,           // subject,   
               strlen(src),   // length,   
               0,             // startoffset,   
               0,             // options,   
               ovector,       // ovector,   
               OVECCOUNT)     // ovecsize,   
      )!=PCRE_ERROR_NOMATCH)  
    {
       printf("\nOK, string has matched ...there are %d matchups\n\n",rc); //  
       for (i = 0; i < rc; i++)
       {
            char *substring_start = src + ovector[2*i];
            int substring_length = ovector[2*i+1] - ovector[2*i];
            printf("$%2d: %.*s length: %d\n", i, substring_length, substring_start,substring_length);
       }
       src = src + ovector[1];  // to move the src pointer to the end offset of current matchup
       if (!src) break;
    }
pcre_free(re);
```

I got my result:

```
Source : aaa:  bbbb:
Pattern: "a(.*?):|b(.*?):"

OK, string has matched ...there are 2 matches

$ 0: aaa: length: 4
$ 1: aa length: 2 

OK, string has matched ...there are 3 matches

$ 0: bbbb: length: 5
$ 1:  length: 0
$ 2: bbb length: 3
```

And I wonder, how did I get the answer **"$ 1:  length: 0"**?

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Jonathan Leffler I think your answer is right.

Just now I tried

```
Source: "aaa: bbb: ccc:"
Pattern: "c(.+?):|a(.+?):|b(.+?):"
```

and got the result goes like this:

```
$ 0: aaa: length: 4
$ 1:  length: 0
$ 2: aa length: 2

$ 0: bbbb: length: 5
$ 1:  length: 0
$ 2:  length: 0
$ 3: bbb length: 3

$ 0: cccc: length: 5
$ 1: ccc length: 3
```

which proves your answer in reverse:

The capture of the regex stops when a matchup is found, so `aaa:` got captured with `a(.+?):` after trying match `c(.+?):`, and the first line of the result shows the whole string, the #2 shows the result offset matching up with the alternative `c(.+?):`

For b(.+?), it got captured at last in the regex, that explains the two `length : 0`

For c(.+?), it got captured in the first place, so there is no `length : 0`

Comment: Could you augment the example source so that it compiles?

Comment: Maybe because you use `*` instead of `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two captures in the regex, one in each alternative.  However, the captures are numbered left to right.  In the second case, the first (`$1`) capture is empty; there were no `a`'s in what it matched, so the first capture is empty; the second (`$2`) capture has the `b`'s in it that you expect.

It is almost more surprising that there wasn't anything specified for the second capture on the first time it matched.  I guess that the captures are empty if there was no data for them.

Answer (score 0):

A `*` indicates any number, including zero, of characters.  Which means it matches "nothing".  A `+` character should be used instead, which indicates "match at least 1".

Comment: It doesn't answer the question why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pattern `char *pattern = "a+?:|b+?:";`

**EDIT** Noticed that just `"a+:|b+:"` will also work.

Comment: The question asks for why it happens, not for suggestion on the regex, which is likely an example to show the strangeness.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern:

```
a(.*?):
```

This pattern means look for an uncaptured 'a', followed by the capture of any amount of anything, modified to return the smallest matching pattern, followed by an uncaptured ':'.

If you consider the string:

```
aaa:
```

Now think about the last 'a' before the colon:

```
a:
```

It matches the pattern - an 'a', followed by nothing, followed by a colon.  The 'nothing' is captured, which is why you get a zero length result.

Comment: The overall string captured by the second match is `bbbb`; the explanation involving `a:` isn't obviously applicable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give a good example concerning my real problem, however your answer can't explain why there is a `length:0` in the result of `aaa:`